# .NET Copy files to a specified directory where part of the path is generic user

Tags: c#, .net, post-build-event

Inside my .csproj I have added some post build event which copies the built files and copies them to some directory:

```
<Target Name="CopyDLLs" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="Executing CopyDLLs of $(ProjectName) task" Importance="High" />

    <Copy
      SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).dll;$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).pdb;$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).deps.json"
      DestinationFolder="C:\Users\axeman\AppData\Local\MyApp\UserTiles\Dev" />

    <Message Text="Copied build files" Importance="High" />
  </Target>
```

In part of the path:

> ... Users\axeman ....

,can I make the `axeman` as some generic user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is `$(LocalAppData)` to get you to the `c:\users\{someUser}\AppData\Local`

Comment: I have changed to `DestinationFolder="%LOCALAPPDATA%\MyApp\UserTiles\Dev" />` but the folder is created inside the projects folder

Comment: Try `$(LocalAppData)` instead